# how to add a background image slideshow in asp.net with static content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

i want to add an image slideshow as my background to my home page of my asp.net web site which i am currently working on.
i was inspired to do so by this site.....http://www.isb.edu/
my slideshow works fine....but i want it as my background.....
is it possible to do so???
if so then plz help a brother out here.....

my slideshow code is something like this....

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="HOME.aspx.cs" Inherits="webforms_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div>
        <link href="../css%20pages/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <style type="text/css">

         #s_show {
         border-style: none;
             border-color: inherit;
             border-width: 5px;
             position:relative;
             height:349px;
             background-color:#000;
             top: 2px;
             left: 67px;
             width: 1013px;
         }
#s_show IMG {
        border-style: none;
            border-color: inherit;
            border-width: 5px;
            position:absolute;
            top:4px;
            left:2px;
            z-index:8;
            opacity:0.0;
            height: 342px;
            width: 1008px;
        }
#s_show IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}
#s_show IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

     </style>

    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function slideShow() {
            var $active = $('#s_show IMG.active');
            if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#s_show IMG:last');
            var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
            : $('#s_show IMG:first');
            $active.addClass('last-active');
            $next
            .css({ opacity: 0.0 })
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500, function () {
                $active.removeClass('active last-active');
            });
        }

        $(function () {
            setInterval("slideShow()", 5000);
        });
</script>
        </div>
 <h1 style="color: black">WELCOME TO THE HERITAGE ACADEMY
    </h1>
        <h3 style="width: 436px; margin-left: 360px; height: 74px;"><em style="color: black">
            <br />
            THE PLACE WHERE EDUCATION IS NOT A PART OF LIFE....<br />

IT IS LIFE ITSELF....!!!!<br />
            </em></h3>

<div id="s_show">
    <img src="../pics%20for%20site/001.gif" />
    <img src="../pics%20for%20site/002.JPG" />
    <img src="../pics%20for%20site/003.jpg" />
    <img src="../pics%20for%20site/banner_new.jpg" />
    <img src="../pics%20for%20site/about-us-vission-mission.jpg" />
    <img src="../pics%20for%20site/8458__7217__8154758.jpg" />
</div>



    <p style="color: #FFFFFF; width: 1079px;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</span><span class="auto-style3"> 
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        Since inception in 2007, the Academy has developed its base of highly accomplished faculty, world class infrastructure and motivated student body to emerge as one of the premier Institutes in the first degree course in the State. Within this short span of five years, the Academy has already carved a space in the mind of the academicians, students and industries by virtue of organizing a number of seminars and panel discussions on current issues of national and international importance. In the field of academic excellence it has also achieved a very high standard through wonderful performance in University Examinations.<br />
        <br />
        <br />
        </span></strong></p>




</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can't you just use absolute positioning through CSS?

Comment: could you please be a little more specific so as to how i can add the <div> elements and position them sir.i am relatively new to the dot net framework and am learning by myself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onresize = function () {
var h = $(window).height();
 if (h > 733) {
   var MargTop = h - 738;
  $(".footer").css("margin-top", MargTop.toString() + "px");
 }
}
$(function () {
 var h = $(window).height();
 if (h > 733) {
var MargTop = h - 738;
$(".footer").css("margin-top", MargTop.toString() + "px");
 }
 $.vegas('slideshow', {
  delay: 8000,
backgrounds: [
{ src: '....png', fade: 4000 },
{ src: '....png', fade: 4000 },
{ src: '....png', fade: 4000 },
{ src: '....png, fade: 4000 },
]
 
})('overlay');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [JQuery Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) or you can use CSS3, [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/) you can get reference for this.